# Is gcc flags repetition and ordering important?

Tags: gcc, compiler-flags

I see some of `gcc` flags repeated when building C extension for python. When I run:

```
python setup.py build_ext
```

The running build command looks like this:

```
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -flto=4 -fuse-linker-plugin -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O3 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c /tmp/src/source.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/tmp/src/source.o
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -flto=4 -fuse-linker-plugin -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/tmp/src/source.o -L/usr/lib -lpython3.7m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/source.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Ok, that's a long one. But, as you can see some flags are repeated. Here is the repetition in the first command:

- `-O3` repeated 4 times.
- `-fno-plt` repeated  3 times.
- `-fstack-protector-strong` repeated 3 times.
- `-march=x86-64` repeated 3 times.
- `-mtune=generic` repeated 3 times.
- `-pipe` repeated 3 times.

Beside `-Wl,...` flags which are passed to linker, does those flags repetition and ordering have any meanings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not unusual to see repetitions of options in GCC commandlines
that have been generated by some tool-stack (frequently an IDE), with
human input "at the top".

None of the repetitions you have spotted makes any difference to the
meaning of the commandline. Usually such repetitions just amount to innocuous
redundancy, and they can have a rational
motive. A tool that is adding something incrementally to a GCC commandline may
wish to ensure that a certain option is in enabled at that point, even if it
might have been somehow disabled by an option appended since the last occurrence that enabled it. Repeating
the option redundantly may be cheaper than checking whether it is redundant.

**But repetition is not necessarily innocuous...**

If an option `OPT` occurs at some point in the commandline:

```
 ... OPT ...
```

then replacing that one occurrence with 2 or more will not make a difference.

However, if the commandline is of the form:

```
 ... OPT1 ... OPT2 ...
```

Then adding another occurrence of `OPT1` anywhere after `OPT2` may well make a
difference. Likewise adding another occurrence of `OPT2` anywhere before `OPT1`.

That is because the *order* in which options occur very often makes a
difference.

An option is routinely composed of a *flag* and a *value*, e.g

```
 -O3             -> Flag = -O, value = 3
 -I./inc         -> Flag = -I, value = ../inc
```

Some flags, like `-O` can take any one of a set of mutually
exclusive values. Call these *mutex flags*, for short. When a mutex flag occurs repeatedly with
countervailing values, the *last* in the commandline prevails:

```
 -O1 -O2 -O3 = -O3
 -O3 -O2 -O1 = -O1
```

Others flags, like `-I`, can take arbitary
non-exclusive values successively that are accumulated, in their order of occurrence, to form a sequence that
is one of the parameters of compilation or linkage. E.g.

```
 -I./foo -I./bar
```

appends `./foo` and then `./bar` to the user-specified include-directory
search order for compilation. Call these *cumulative flags*.

Other flags are boolean and have an enabling form and a disabling
form , e.g. `-fstack-protector`,
`-fno-stack-protector`. These can be equated to mutex options with
exclusive possible values True and False.

And yet another kind of flag, like `-l`, accepts arbitrary non-exclusive values
successively that are *not* accumulated, but each just becomes the value of the flag
*at that point* in the commandline. For all I can recall, `-l` is the only flag of this kind,
which is an anomalous kind: `-lfoo` isn't really an *option* so much as a *positional argument*
to which the flag attaches a method of interpretation. It says that a file
`libfoo.{so|a}` is to be input to the linkage *at this point*, whose absolute pathname
the linker is to discover algorithmically (with reference to the `-L` options). Let's
call such flags *positional flags*.

For mutex flags, the meaning of a commandline can be changed if an option
occurring somewhere is repeated later. E.g.

```
 -fno-stack-protector -O1 -O3 -fstack-protector
```

already looks as if too many cooks have been spoiling the broth, and
is equivalent to:

```
 -O3 -fstack-protector
```

But if we append some repetition:

```
 -fno-stack-protector -O1 -O3 -fstack-protector -fno-stack-protector -O1
```

it becomes equivalent to:

```
 -O1 -fno-stack-protector
```

For cumulative flags, it's easier to envisage messing with the meaning
of the commandline by repeating an option *before* some occurrence than after:

```
 -I./foo -I./bar
```

means what it says. Whereas

```
 -I./bar -I./foo -I./bar
```

means the same as:

```
 -I./bar -I./foo
```

But that sort of messing hardly happens in practice, because repetitions of
options are almost always generated by *appending*
a repetition to a commandline during incremental construction.

Positional flags are by definition sensitive to *order*, both amongst themselves
and in relation to other options and positional arguments. Every permutation of

```
 ... -lfoo -lbar main.o ...
```

yields a different linkage. And *repetition* of options with positional flags
can also easily make a difference. Notoriously,

```
... -lfoo main.o ...
```

may well result in a linkage failure, which

```
    ... -lfoo main.o -lfoo
```

would fix.

So emphatically, yes, repetition and ordering of flags can be important.